# jQuery show more details on click

Tags: jquery

I would like to seek your help in resolving this issue. I want to reveal more details inside a div upon clicking a link in that div. However, there will over 50 divs in a single page. I can't give ids to each div and clickable link. Is there any we we can achieve this?

Here is what I have tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready (function(){
    $('#clk').click(function(e){
      $('.1').css({'height':'500px', 'background-color': '#ffbbbb'} );
      $(this).hide ();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
```

clk is the id of the clickable link. .1 is the class of the div.

As mentioned earlier, going by what I have done, I have to use 50 ids and 50 classes

Here is the HTML of that part

```
<div class="1">
    <ul>
    <li><img src="images/thumb/someimage.jpg"></li>
    <li><h2>Title Text </h2></li>
    <li><h3>Summary</h3></li>
    <li><p> para goes here. <a class="clk" href="#">Click</a></p>
    </li></ul>

</div>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: can you share html part ? If i can see html hierarchy, i'll suggest parent() closest() functions.

Comment: I have added the html part.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use IDs to find things, it's not the only way. Make things relative. Use `closest`, `next` etc to find your shower from your clicker. (It would be a better answer if you showed your HTML structure, too.)

EDIT: Okay, finally got what you were saying. Reading comprehension fail on my part. So, first, let's rename `.1` to something sensible, say... `.expandable`:

```
<div class="expandable">
  <ul>
  <li><img src="images/thumb/someimage.jpg"></li>
  <li><h2>Title Text </h2></li>
  <li><h3>Summary</h3></li>
  <li><p> para goes here. <a class="clk" href="#">Click</a></p>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

You could do:

```
$('.clk').click(function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.expandable').css({'height':'500px', 'background-color': '#ffbbbb'} );
  $(this).hide();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

So, `.closest` goes up from the current element, finding the nearest ancestor that matches. This way, you can get get the appropriate `.expandable` from each `.clk`, no need for IDs or 50 class names.

Although, having auto height would probably be better in most circumstances than fixed 500, unless you absolutely know exactly how much stuff you have.

Comment: Hi i have added the html part.. Thank you

Comment: @Gops: " I want to reveal more details inside a div upon clicking a link in that div." but "`.hide()`"... Something doesn't fit. Please clarify what you actually want. Did you mean "I want to *hide* more details..."? Or, if you want to show something, where would this something go?

Comment: Am sorry if my query has made you confused.. I have a div that has a width of 300 px and height of 350 px. (like wise 50 divs). The Div by default shows an Image/ Title Text/ Paragraph. There is also a link that says 'Click for more'. By clicking that the Div height has to be increased and show some more details (lets say another paragraph).. Sir is this Okay

Comment: Hi Sir, Thanks.. Its working.. I have added "e" in the "$('.clk').click(function() {" and then it worked. Many thanks for your code and the time you have spent.. One small question.. Instead of hiding the Click for More.. Could we change that to the text "Still More Details" and clicking on that opens a pop-div.. Sorry if i have gone too far.. Thanks again for all the help

Comment: @Gops: Of course you could. But it would arguably be easier to have a different div that you `.show()` when you `.hide()` the other one.

Comment: Okay.. got it.. I tried to add another function to reinstate the div back to original height..But that's not working.. Is there an option where we can use a common text link to show more and show less..

Comment: Could you please verify whether this is an okay code: 
 
$(document).ready (function(){
 $('.expandable').mouseover(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
 $(this).css({'height':'600px', 'background-color': '#fff'} );
 
 }); 
 $('.expandable').mouseout(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.expandable').css({'height':'300px', 'background-color': '#dedede'} );
  
  
 })
});

Comment: Hi Sir.. There is  a small issue with the code supplied by you. As i said there are 50 divs.. When I clicked on the 2nd Div link.. The Second as well as the first Div expands.. Why this is so..

Comment: @Gops: I really can't tell you unless you put some example code, preferably on jsfiddle.com. What I wrote should not be able to do that, because `.closest()` will only ever match one element. Also, your code you wrote in the comments is likely not correct, since you're looking for a closest `.expandable` to an `.expandable`, which I can't imagine making sense in the scenario you described.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to have individual classes and IDs for everything. I'd add a common class to all 50 of these items that describe what it's holding. I'd then approach it like this:

```
$('.common-class a').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('.common-class').find('.more').slideToggle();
});
```

The `.find('.more')` will only find the `.more` div inside of the `.common-class` link you've clicked.

Here's a brief demo: http://jsbin.com/alijak/1/edit

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the quick reply. I am facing issue small issue though. The Div class has a fixed height, so calling another div in that is not serving purpose as intended. I actually want to increase height of the Div, so that it shows the contents, which initially is hidden. Is there any way to switch the class or add css to the existing DIV. Any way to do that..

Comment: Hi Bill, Thanks for the help.. Even though your approach is also viable..Amadan's has the option that best suited me.. Thanks for considering my query..

Comment: No problem! Have fun!